# Two buttons side by side with a background image

Tags: android

I wish to have two large buttons side by side. They should take up the full with of the screen (i.e. half the width each). I want the background of the buttons to contain an image (which will be scaled down from a source image much larger than the button). I want the height of the buttons to be dictated by the aspect ratio of the image. Preferably all done in xml. Can it be done?

I tried the following, only to find that the buttons appeared square, even though the images are much wider than they are tall (and both images have the same dimensions).

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rep_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/repeating"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/oneoff_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/oneoff"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you attempted this at all?

Comment: Just added my non-working code.

Comment: Sadly, Button doesn't let you set a scaletype (this would be trivial with an ImageButton). Is ImageButton an option, or do you need to set the text?

Comment: ImageButton is an option

Comment: In that case, create an ImageButton and set the scaletype to CENTER_INSIDE.

Comment: does it even make sense to set the size of the button based on the image , when you wish to tile it ... ?

Comment: Its only being "tiled" horizontally... i.e. there are just two buttons on the entire screen and I have complete flexibility about their height... so I just want the height to be whatever makes the background image look good.

Comment: Hmmm... just tried android:scaleType="CENTER_INSIDE" and now the buttons are squished too flat. The image contains a circle and it appears elliptical.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `ImageButton` I believe they will scale based on the size of the image being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/retro_blue_background"
    android:text="Übernehmen" >

</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/retro_blue_background"
    android:text="Abbrechen" >

</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Is that what you want?]

Comment: those circles look rather elliptical to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `ImageView`, and set the clickable attribute to true. You can then treat it like a `Button` by setting an `onClickListener`, but it will take care of the aspect ratio of the image, with out adding a gray border as it does with a `ImageButton`.